# yticks does not show correctly when mixing plotyy and semilogy in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I am plotting two curves in different axes in the same figure with plotyy. The first curve ranges from 10^-4 to 10^-1 and the second curve ranges from 0 to 10. If I plot in the following way,

[AX, H1, H2] = plotyy(x, y1, x, y2, 'semilogy', 'semilogy');

They will both plotted as semilogy and with correct scale in y. But I don't want to show y2 in log10 scale, so I change

[AX, H1, H2] = plotyy(x, y1, x, y2, 'semilogy', 'plot');

However, then on left and right y axis, the tick only show the min and max range, all detail inbetween gone. Why's that?

Comment: I think I've run into this before, and the solution was to set the tick marks manually, which is a little tricky because there are two sets of y-ticks to work with! I will try to find the code tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
%# create some data resembling what you described
x = 1:100;
y1 = rand(size(x))*1e-1 + 1e-4;
y2 = rand(size(x))*10;

%# plot
hAx = plotyy(x,y1, x,y2, 'semilogy', 'semilogy');
set(hAx(2), 'YScale','linear')
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
[AX, H1, H2] = plotyy(x, y1, x, y2, 'semilogy', 'plot');

% set yticks for the left axis 
set(AX(1), 'ytick', yourDesiredYticks1)
set(AX(1), 'box', 'off') % to remove corresponding yticks on the right side of the plot

% set yticks for the right axis
set(AX(2), 'ytick', yourDesiredYticks2)
set(AX(2), 'box', 'off')
```

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest, except that I wasn't aware of the `box off` stuff before. But `box off` not only removes the ticks from the "other" side of the axis, it removes the ticks (and border line) from the top of the plot as well. What I typically do instead is to make sure that there are the same number of tick marks on each side. This has the advantage that you can turn on grid lines and have things look decent.